# C++ strange behaviour mutator vector

Tags: c++, vector, mutators

I've been working on a work for school where we have to create a Client class with 4 string, 4 int and a vector(int) as the last argument. The problem is, when i want to print all of the vector's elements, if i use my mutator directly, it is printing nonsence.

```
vector<int> v_int;
vector<int>::iterator it_v_i;
v_int.push_back(2);
v_int.push_back(3);
v_int.push_back(7);
v_int.push_back(1);

Client client("nom1", "prenom1", "adress1", "city1", "comment1", 1240967102, 44522, 5, 10, v_int);

v_int = client.getIdResources();
for (it_v_i = v_int.begin(); it_v_i != v_int.end(); it_v_i++) {
    cout << *it_v_i << ", ";
}
```

print 2,3,7,1 as expected, but the following code

```
for (it_v_i = client.getIdResources().begin(); it_v_i != client.getIdResources().end(); it_v_i++) {
    cout << *it_v_i << ", ";
}
```

print unidentified number (like 3417664...), unidentified number, 7, 1

I really don't understand why this is happening

**EDIT :**

Constructor :

```
Client::Client(const string& name, const string& surname, const string& adress, const string& city, const string& comment,
            const int& phoneNb, const int& postalCode, const int& termAppointment, const int& priority, const vector<int>& idResources)
                : name(name), surname(surname), adress(adress), city(city), comment(comment), phoneNumber(phoneNb),
                postalCode(postalCode), termAppointment(termAppointment), priority(priority), idResources(idResources)
```

{
}

Mutator :

```
std::vector<int> getIdResources() const{ return idResources; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in second snippet *two* temporary `vector`s are being used to obtain the `begin()` and `end()` iterators (assuming the declaration is `std::vector<int> client.getIdResources()` and not `std::vector<int>& client.getIdResources()`). This means that `it_v_i` is referring to the elements of a destructed `std::vector`. When `it_v_i` is dereferenced it causes undefined behaviour.

To make the second code snippet function correctly a reference to the `std::vector` needs to be returned by `client.getIdResources()`. However, returning references to internal class members introduces other problems, such as lifetime issues.

Comment: So this mean the 1st case is the only one way to do it properly ?

Comment: @DadEapPurple, yes or modify `getIdResources()` to return a `const std::vector<int>&`.